# How to convert the winrt::ImageSource to OpenCV cv::Mat in C++/winrt?

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-runtime, winui-3, winui

I want to convert the winrt type ImageSouce to cv::Mat. However, I cannot get the data pointer of the ImageSource.

```
cv::Mat ToMat(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::ImageSource const& from)
    {
        return cv::Mat();
    }
```

```
cv::Mat ImageConverter::ToMat(winrt::SoftwareBitmap const& from)
    {
        winrt::BitmapBuffer buffer = from.LockBuffer(winrt::BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
        unsigned char* pPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(buffer.CreateReference());
        auto interop = reference.as<Windows::Foundation::IMemoryBufferByteAccess>();
        uint8_t* pixels{};
        uint32_t capacity{};
        winrt::check_hresult(interop->GetBuffer(&pixels, &capacity));
        cv::Mat mat(from.PixelHeight(), from.PixelWidth(), CV_8UC4);
        memcpy(mat.data, pixels, 4ull * from.PixelHeight() * from.PixelWidth());
        return mat;
    }
cv::Mat ToMat(winrt::WriteableBitmap const& from)
    {
        auto pPixels = from.PixelBuffer().data();
        cv::Mat mat(from.PixelHeight(), from.PixelWidth(), CV_8UC4);
        memcpy(mat.data, pPixels, 4ull * from.PixelHeight() * from.PixelWidth());
        return mat;
    }
```

There are the conversion function. How do I get the date pointer then to convert it like those.

Comment: if you are using a BitmapImage as the ImageSource, you can load the image file into a SoftwareBitmap and then convert the SoftwareBitmap to a cv::Mat using the ToMat function that you provided.

Comment: ImageSource is like an abstract class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.imagesource), sort of. It ultimately depends on the type of ImageSource. How did you get that in the first place?

Comment: You can use [BitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder?view=winrt-22621) to get pixel data from image files. Also see https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2FWindows-universal-samples%20WriteableBitmap&type=code for possible samples.